# gulp-livereload en Android/iOs

Tags: android, ios, symfony, gulp

Tengo montado un servidor symfony en local para desarrollar (el que viene con el propio symfony) y uso gulp con gulp-liveroald para manejar los cambios en el css y que se reflejen de manera instantánea. 
En localhost del propio ordenador obviamente funciona. Pero claro si me conecto desde el móvil a mí localhost la web carga bien pero el livereload no funciona (estará escuchando a localhost del móvil y no al server del ordenador).

¿Cómo puedo configurarlo para usarlo desde cualquier dispositivo externo que se conecte al server?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, lo he solucionado cargando el livereload.js de mi server:

```
 <script src="http://mi.server.ip.host:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></script>
```

Entonces ahora solo tengo que hacer un código para que si la petición a la página se realiza desde localhost, el livereload.js se cargue desde localhost y si se realiza desde otra ip, se cargue desde la ip del servidor.